# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when using lastIndexOf()

Tags: c#, substring, lastindexof

I'm really stumped as to why I'm getting an exception. Here is a SSCCE I put together to demonstrate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string tmp =
               "Child of: View Available Networks (197314), Title: N/A  (66244)";
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);

    int one = tmp.LastIndexOf('('), two = tmp.LastIndexOf(')');

    //my own error checking
    Console.WriteLine(tmp.Length);//returns 63
    Console.WriteLine(one < 0);//returns false
    Console.WriteLine(two > tmp.Length);//returns false
    Console.WriteLine(one);//returns 56
    Console.WriteLine(two);//returns 62

    /*
     * error occurs here.
     * ArgumentOutOfRangeException Index and length must refer to
     * a location within the string.
     * Parameter name: length
     */
    string intptr = tmp.Substring(one, two);

    Console.WriteLine(intptr);
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong (though coming from a Java background it might be trivial), hopefully someone else can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`substring`s 2nd parameter is the length of the string you want to extract and not the position in the string.

You could do

```
string intptr = tmp.Substring(one + 1, two - one - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
tmp.Substring(one, two);
```

should be

```
tmp.Substring(one, (two-one+1));
```

second parameter is the length of the substring you wantwhile i think you're using it like it were the ending index.
And because i love LINQ, it might also be done like this:

```
string.Join(string.Empty, s.Skip(5).Take(7 - 5 + 1)); //build a string from IEnumerable<char>
```

Comment: Thank you +1 loved the LINQ part

Comment: How would you cast it back to a string? sorry Im new at this :P `string newStr=tmp.Skip(one).Take(two - one);`

Comment: I really need more coffee. Fixed again, I always forget the IEnumerable<> caveats. I'm clearing up some comments.

Answer (score 1):

string.Substring(startIndex, **count**)
you wrote startIndex and finishIndex, it's wrong